# Getting extra slashes while using JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am getting some extra slashes while making json array using PHP. My code is below.

```
<?php
$output=array(array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA001","subject"=>"Mathematics"),array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA002","subject"=>"History"),array("first_name"=>"Rama","last_name"=>"Nayidu","reg_no"=>13,"paper_code"=>"BA001","subject"=>"Geology"),array("first_name"=>"robin","last_name"=>"sahoo","reg_no"=>12,"paper_code"=>"BA003","subject"=>"Science"));
$result = []; // Initialize result array
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $name = $value['first_name'] . ' ' . $value['last_name'];

    // check if same name already has entry, create one if not
    if (!array_key_exists($name, $result)) {
        $result[$name] = array(
            'reg_no' => $value['reg_no'],
            'name' => $name,
            'paper1' => '',
            'paper2' => '',
            'paper3' => '',
            'paper4' => ''
            );
    }

    // count array elements with value, then set paper number and value
    $paper = 'paper' . (count(array_filter($result[$name])) - 1);
    $result[$name][$paper] = $value['paper_code'].'/'.$value['subject'];
}

$result = array_values($result); // reindex result array 
echo json_encode($result);exit;
?>
```

Here the json output is given below.

```
[{"reg_no":12,"name":"robin sahoo","paper1":"BA001\/Mathematics","paper2":"BA002\/History","paper3":"BA003\/Science","paper4":""},{"reg_no":13,"name":"Rama Nayidu","paper1":"BA001\/Geology","paper2":"","paper3":"","paper4":""}]
```

Here my problem is I am adding `$value['paper_code'].'/'.$value['subject'];` and in output I am getting `"BA001\/Mathematics"`. Here One extra slash(`\`) is added which I need to remove.

Comment: Think of [`JSON`](http://json.org) as a blackbox. When you encode some data structure as JSON, you don't care how it looks like internally. You save the JSON or send it to a different computer or application. When you need to use the data again use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get it back. Your JSON is fine, don't worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as the second parameter. LIke:

```
$result = array_values($result); // reindex result array 
echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);exit;
```

This will result to:

```
[{"reg_no":12,"name":"robin sahoo","paper1":"BA001/Mathematics","paper2":"BA002/History","paper3":"BA003/Science","paper4":""},{"reg_no":13,"name":"Rama Nayidu","paper1":"BA001/Geology","paper2":"","paper3":"","paper4":""}]
```

Doc: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)